# OCR and Text Mining on multiple Files using R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, vector

I have a list or data frame (can be either or) of strings (e.g. "78465", "65481", "78486", etc.)

The aforementioned strings will be used to specify file paths of pdfs. So, if there are 10 strings, there will be 10 different pdfs. (e.g. "C:/Users/pdfs/78465.pdf", "C:/Users/pdfs/65481.pdf", "C:/Users/pdfs/78486.pdf", etc.)

I want to read in each pdf, perform OCR and text extraction on the pdf, and then output may rows of data consisting of what I extracted. I want to do this for every pdf.

The output can be 1 large file (data frame or list) consisting of all the extracted text for each pdf with the pdf strings as row IDs or the output can be a file for each pdf each of which consists of the extracted text for that pdf.

The OCR and Text extraction code is about 50 lines of code so I didn't think a function or loop would be the best method for this. Maybe some vectorization?

I'm an amateur R user/programmer, so apologies if the solution is very obvious. I have been searching for an answer for weeks now and I will appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for creating the file paths `v1 <- c("78465", "65481");
> sprintf("C:/Users/pdfs/%s.pdf", v1)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun for the response. Sorry, if I wasn't clear in my original post. My question is how do I take a list of values and one by one run them through the R script and output some data for each value that is run through the script.